# DVD player for Windows 10

Tags: media-player, windows-10, optical-media

I used Windows WMP for DVD, but computer upgrades and Windows 10 WMP does not support DVD playback. I have free VLC but it hands DVD reader and is not usable for DVD. I have embedded Acer Clear.fi player but it is digusting - I don't like that navigator line automatically disappers and that there is no shortcut keys for Play and Resume.

So - what else (preferably free) DVD players are available for Windows 10?

Comment: Here are some software available to try :
[link to site](http://dvd-player-software-review.toptenreviews.com/) but still i will recommend using vlc, for using it after inserting the DVD right click on the icon of the dvd in Mypc it will open the files, there you can find the main video to play with vlc which will give you the main dvd windows

Answer (score 1):

On this genre there is quite a lot of options - freeware, shareware, adware (just kidding :)

However the it  mostly depends on user's choice, whether the you wish to spend a lot of money to buy the software or you wish to have a free alternative.

If the later case is true I would recommend [5K Player](https://www.5kplayer.com). (otherwise Cyberlink PowerDVD)

> Extra features provided by this free Windows 10 DVD player:
>
> - Play videos music in all popular formats like MP4, AVI, MKV, HEVC, MOV, WMV, MP3, FLAC, AAC, WMA, WAV, etc;
> - Free download videos/movies/music from YouTube, Facebook, Dailymotion, Vimeo and other 300+ online video sites;
> - Stream videos audios for iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, etc;
> - Convert videos to MP3, AAC, MP4 for free.

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely recommend **VLC (VideoLan)**. It comes with support of most media formats in addition to DVDs and also enables you to convert/stream/rip any media. It is, of course, **for free.**

Comment: That is the product that the OP says he does not want.